# C++ AMP How to return values in GPU memory?

Tags: c++-amp

Suppose I have an algorithm like so:

```
array a = foo();
array b = bar(a);
array c = foobar(a, b);
array d = fbar(a, c);
```

Now this is fine on the CPU and in CUDA, where I can have functions that return a pointer to a block of gpu memory and then have another function consumes that intermediate value.

How do you do this in C++ AMP? I am guessing you have to use the concurrency::array object but I cant find any sample code doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an actual C++ AMP example:

```
concurrency::array<int, 1> bar(const concurrency::array<int, 1>& input)
{
  parallel_for_each(b.extent, [&b, &r](concurrency::index<1> idx)
  {
    input[idx] = ...;
  });
  return input;
}
```

As Simon points out array<> supports move so this should be quite efficient. You might want to consider using array_view for better code flexibility rather than array<>.

You could further tidy this up by moving the return value of bar, rather than doing an implicit copy.

Comment: +1 Why move the return of bar? according to the standard, RVO must be invoked in this case, so the given example would be right?

Comment: I updated the code to match the original semantics for bar(). However if you're passing input in and out it might be better to have a void function and remove the const from the input parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The concurrency::array class is just like any other templated class in C++.  There's no syntactic magic here.  So you could do this:

```
using namespace concurrency;  // because I hate typing

array<int, 1> foo(int size)
{
    return array<int, 1>(size);
}

array<int, 1> bar(array<int, 1> input)
{
    // do something to input
    return input;
}

array<int> a = bar(foo(1024));
```

This probably produces more deep copies than you'd like.  But using pointers or references in whatever way you are comfortable will address that.

But none of this is specific to AMP.  This is just using C++11 in this code.

Comment: Please note that concurrency:array type defines move constructors, so no extra copies would occur.